# No Content Showing on AMP Pages When Linked From Google Search Results?

Tags: amp-html

We have had to disable our AMP pages as when they are linked to from Google search results no article content displays. The pages work perfectly when you go to the URL directly, they give no errors when you run them through google's AMP Test, but when you preview via search result in google search console the article content does not display (same as when in production). We use the AMP plugin for WP from Automattic, we have checked for issues with other plugins potentially affecting the content, disabled our DFP served ads in case they were causing the issue, but haven't found anything.

I have attached a screen grab of how the articles look when linked via google search results, showing where the missing content should be. You can see our AMP pages on our staging environment here for e.g. http://stage.dmarge.com/2016/05/how-to-dress-cocktail-men.html/amp . Has anyone come across this issue or have any suggestions for what we can try to resolve the issue? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f1wW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The page looks great in general. You can use this tool to investigate https://search.google.com/test/amp but you will have to unblock GoogleBot from accessing it temporarily.

The page also renders fine on the AMP cache
https://stage-dmarge-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/stage.dmarge.com/2016/05/how-to-dress-cocktail-men.html/amp